# Remove CKEdit Instance

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I can't seem to destroy instances of CKEdit per the documentation.

Consider the following:

```
<input name="txt1" type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="create()">Create</a><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="destroy()">Destroy</a>
<script type= "text/javascript" >
<!--
function create() {
    var hEd = CKEDITOR.instances['txt1'];
    if (hEd) {
        CKEDITOR.remove(hEd);
    }
    hEd = CKEDITOR.replace('txt1');
}
function destroy(){
    var hEd = CKEDITOR.instances['txt1'];
    if (hEd) {
        CKEDITOR.remove(hEd);
    }
}
-->
</script>
```

When destroy() runs, CKEDITOR.remove(hEd); is being called.  Multiple clicks to create() produce multiple instances of CKEditor on screen, but their instances no longer appear in CKEDITOR.instances.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You must use hEd.destroy ([editor.destroy()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy)).

[CKEDITOR.remove()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.remove) is for internal use as stated in the API.

Comment: Followed a bad snippet.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @AlfonsoML Thanks for this - you just saved me raging :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you use CKEDITOR.remove() then instance isn't destroyed. You need to call sth like: instance.destroy() to remove old one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```js
CKEDITOR.instances['textareaId'].destory()
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use:

```
<textarea name="tx1" id="tx1" rows="15" cols="106"></textarea>
```

CKEDITOR.instances['tx1'] = false;