# How to destroy inline CKEditor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, destroy

Let's say that this is code I have:

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable></div>

// This is working for me
$('.editor').click(function(){
   $(this).ckeditor();
});

// This is the problem
$('.editor').on('focusout', function(){
   $(this).ckeditorDestroy(); // What will destroy ckeditor?
});
```

I know that this function doesn't exists, but I didn't found nothing what was working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all CKEditor instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687627/remove-all-ckeditor-instances)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor">Editor 1!</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor">Editor 2!</div>
```

JS

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

$( '.editor' ).click( function(){
    $( this ).ckeditor( function() {
        console.log( 'Instance ' + this.name + ' created' );
    }, {
        on: {
            blur: function( evt ) {
                console.log( 'Instance ' + this.name + ' destroyed' );
                this.destroy();
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Use [editor#blur](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur) event rather than `focusout` or similar because i.e opening editor dialog does not mean that editor is blurred, while `focusout` may be fired in such case. It's much safer. [More about jQuery adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery).

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
$('.editor').on('focusout', function(){
   $(this).ckeditor(function(){
        this.destroy();
    });
});
```

Comment: You made something that worked exactly as I wanted: "this.ckeditor... this destroy".

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this with ES6. For ES5, swap `instance.attr("title").includes(name)` with `instance.attr("title").indexOf(name) !== -1;`

```
function disableCKEDITORInstance(instance) {
    var instance = $(instance);
    instance.removeClass("selected");
    instance.attr("contenteditable", "false");
    for(name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        if (instance.attr("title").includes(name)){
            CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
        }
    }
}
```