# Saving content while using CKeditor inline

Tags: javascript, save, ckeditor, inline

I'm currently using the inline option within CKeditor (4.4.2) to edit different areas in a HTML file. What I want to do is to save the HTML file after someone stops editing a editable area (after the editor closes). But I can't find any information on how to do this in the CKeditor documentation.

Does someone know anything about how to do this? I was excepting some sort of an event to listen to, but I could not find this in the documentation.

Comment: u can do this with ajax post only ....

Comment: Yes, I understand. But you also need to bind the AJAX script to an event. Saving the content isn't the problem, but I dont know how to do this when the user is done editing within an area (for example, the users clicks outside of the editor (editor closes) or the users clicks the next editable area (editor still closes and a new one opens).

Comment: you can just use focusout() events in jquery...

Comment: What do you mean by "after the editor closes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [editor#blur](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur) and [editor#change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) events (depending on your needs). Do not use `focusout` because CKEditor is far more complicated than that (see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533286/how-to-destroy-inline-ckeditor-with-jquery/24534169#24534169) to know why).

You may also find a built-in events buffer ([CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-eventsBuffer)) useful to reduce the number of AJAX calls.

Some ol' [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/xfvrA/).

Comment: Thx! Really could not find this in the documentation! Have it up and running already! It is always difficult to search if you do not know what you should look for ;)